# Creating a table Summary using R

Tags: r, summary

I have a dataset with 2 columns as shown. What I want to do is plot a table summary with rows as groups (1-5, 6-10, 11-15, 16-20) and the columns as the % of yes and no. Don't have the code as I don't know how to start. But I have the dataset.

```
Col 1   Col 2
 1       Yes
 2       No
 3       Yes
 4       No
 5       No
 6       No
 7       Yes
 8       Yes
 9       Yes
10       No
12       Yes
14       No
16       No
18       No
20       Yes
```

Comment: I want the first column of the summary as groups 1-5, 6-10, .... the second column as Yes and the third column as No. Under Yes and No, I want the % of Yess and Nos.

Comment: No. Not a duplicate. The link shows a different example.

Answer (score 1):

A base R solution could envolve `cut` and `aggregate`.

```
f <- cut(dat$Col.1, c(1, 6, 11, 16, 21, Inf),
         include.lowest = TRUE, right = FALSE)
agg <- aggregate(Col.2 ~ f, dat, table)
agg <- cbind(agg[1], agg[[2]])
agg[2:3] <- 100*agg[2:3]/rowSums(agg[2:3])

agg
#        f       No      Yes
#1   [1,6) 60.00000 40.00000
#2  [6,11) 40.00000 60.00000
#3 [11,16) 50.00000 50.00000
#4 [16,21) 66.66667 33.33333
```

**Data.**

```
dat <-
structure(list(Col.1 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 12L, 14L, 16L, 18L, 20L), Col.2 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("No", 
"Yes"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Using only base R and `DF` from the Note at the end:

```
nr <- nrow(DF)
group <- 5 * ceiling(DF$Col1 / 5)
100 * prop.table(xtabs(~ group + Col2, DF), 1)
```

giving:

```
     Col2
group       No      Yes
   5  60.00000 40.00000
   10 40.00000 60.00000
   15 50.00000 50.00000
   20 66.66667 33.33333
```

**2)** or with fancier group labels try this giving nicer labels than some other methods:

```
nr <- nrow(DF)

g <- 5 * ceiling(DF$Col1 / 5) # from above
labels <- unique(paste0(g-4, "-", g))
group <- factor(g, labels = labels)

tab <- 100 * prop.table(xtabs(~ group + Col2, DF), 1)
```

giving:

```
> tab
       Col2
group         No      Yes
  1-5   60.00000 40.00000
  6-10  40.00000 60.00000
  11-15 50.00000 50.00000
  16-20 66.66667 33.33333

> # another layout
> ftable(tab, row.vars = 1:2)

group Col2          
1-5   No    60.00000
      Yes   40.00000
6-10  No    40.00000
      Yes   60.00000
11-15 No    50.00000
      Yes   50.00000
16-20 No    66.66667
      Yes   33.33333

> plot(tab, col = c("pink", "lightgreen"))
```

[image: screenshot]

### Note

The input `DF` in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "Col1   Col2
 1       Yes
 2       No
 3       Yes
 4       No
 5       No
 6       No
 7       Yes
 8       Yes
 9       Yes
10       No
12       Yes
14       No
16       No
18       No
20       Yes"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

### Update

Revised several times.